# How to fix PATH recognition in Linux Bash

Tags: bash, shell, executable

I have been searching for how to avoid multiple instances of a running program.

I am not able to execute cat or rm in my script:

> line 19: cat: command not found

> line 21: rm: command not found

Comment: Your `PATH` seems to be messed up.

Comment: This is weird: your system does not find `cat` or `rm` (both being present in `/usr/bin`, but is does not complain about `kill` (being present in the same directory). Can you check the directories of those commands and edit your question accordingly? (`which <command>`)

Comment: @Dominique I don't think it ever runs `kill` because the expression to complete the `kill` command line (including `cat`) fails.

Comment: @B.Morris: you're right. Nevertheless I don't think the problem can be solved without verifying the whereabouts of the `cat` and the `rm` commands, for which, as indicated by Benjamin, the value of the `PATH` variable can be interesting too (result of the `env` command).

Comment: @Dominique i think you might be right, i just checked the directory and all of the commands are written here in "/usr/bin/", though not sure why they arent able to be executed. Will check more about the PATH

Comment: @Xero: in that case, I'd advise you to check your `PATH` variable and see how you can add the `/usr/bin` directory to that variable.

Comment: Yup ive just added the PATH again and it works! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

This does not address the command not found problem.

Testing the existence of a file before creating it introduces a race condition. Creating a directory is an atomic action.

```sh
declare -r LOCKDIR='program.run'
declare -r PIDFILE="$LOCKDIR/program.pid"

if ! mkdir "$LOCKDIR"; then
  # the lockdir already exists.
  # some unavoidable potential race conditions in here
  if [[ -f "$PIDFILE" ]]; then
    pid=$(< "$PIDFILE" )
    if kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null; then
      echo "Another process is running with the last stored PID" >&2
      # no guarantee that it's actually this program
      # you can check it if you want (use pgrep, or "/proc/$pid/cmdline" if you're on linux)
      exit 1
    fi
    # if we get here, there's no process with that pid,
    # so it should be safe to carry on
  fi
fi

# write the pidfile
echo "$$" > "$PIDFILE"
```

You should delete the lockdir even if the program exits unexpectedly:

```sh
cleanup() {
  rm "$LOCKDIR/$PIDFILE" &&
  rmdir "$LOCKDIR" ||
  echo "can't cleanup the lock directory" >&2
}
trap cleanup EXIT
```

Comment: Thank you for the Information, its very helpful! ill be currently checking the PATH to see why it isnt registering cat, rm ...